# How to compute a zero spread for unexpected loss

Tags: cds, default-probability

I have to discount a cash flows of mezzanine and junior note of NPL's securization, so the discount curve have to include a zero spread for unexpected loss, could you suggest me a proxy to estimate quickly this spread?

I tried to use the differences between the

- CDS Benchmark CCC Western Europe 5Y and
- the spread derived from 5Y probability of default of the ABS EMEA transition matrix published by Fitch.

but, I obtained a negative spread, while, I need a positive spread to represent the unexpected loss.

Other suggestions?

Many Thanks

Comment: is NPL a non-performing loan?

Comment: Yes, NPL = Non-Performing Loans.